# Trouble switching to NVdia GPU in 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, 18.04

When I try to run `nvidia-settings` to switch GPUs, the following output shows up:

```
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded


ERROR: Error querying enabled displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).


ERROR: Error querying connected displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).

** Message: 22:22:22.703: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 22:22:22.703: PRIME: is it supported? no

ERROR: Unable to open file '/home/uruwi/.nvidia-settings-rc' for writing.
```

I've rebooted several times and reïnstalled the nvidia drivers to no avail. I also tried running `sudo nvidia-xconfig`, but the generated file [causes problems](https://gist.github.com/bluebear94/b588ddd09510b7cc00480bac431b0c95).

Edit 1/?: `sudo modprobe nvidia` fails because of an "exec format error", if that information is useful. `dmesg` gives the following lines:

```
[ 1066.385988] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[ 1066.395098] module: x86/modules: Skipping invalid relocation target, existing value is nonzero for type 1, loc 00000000873cc009, val ffffffffc2c20430
```

Edit 2/?: I tried running the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt purge nvidia*
sudo apt install nvidia-390
```

Now `nvidia-settings` gives the following error:

```
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded


ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
```

If I run `nvidia-xconfig` and try to start the X server, [this](https://gist.github.com/bluebear94/473e4b6cac1d0242567fba823ddfee0c) gets put into the log.

Edit 3/?:

```
$ uname -a
Linux uruwi-HP-ENVY-x360-m6-Convertible 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Edit 4/?: Tried using `bumblebee` but `optirun` fails because... it can't load the driver.

Edit 5/?: Great, I edited the bumblebee configuration but now `optirun` gives a `Cannot access secondary GPU, secondary X is not active.` error.

Edit 6/?: Manually installed the nvidia driver and I still can't load it (with [more debug info](https://gist.github.com/bluebear94/af79170ad99713a9600b80d63a7c6870)):

```
$ sudo modprobe nvidia
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': Exec format error
```

Edit 7/?: Managed to get a loadable nvidia driver by temporarily switching `cc` to gcc 7.3.0 before installing. However, Cinnamon crashes now, probably because X can't initialise any GLX extension. Here's [Xorg.0.log](https://gist.github.com/bluebear94/c54939ac314d0ed88fd3bc26fa6032c3).

Edit 8/?: Reïnstalling `xserver-xorg-core` as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487760/peaceful-coexistance-of-intel-and-nviidia-glx) solves the X error, but the problem is that now I can't use the nvidia drivers.

Edit 9/?: Invoking `nvidia-xconfig` makes glsanity report the proper driver for the NVidia card, but when I try to actually run a program under `optirun`, I get an X BadMatch error on `GLX` / `X_GLXSwapBuffers`.

Edit 10/? but I hope it's 10: realised that having CodeXL installed is causing `apt purge` to not really purge packages. Trying purging everything NVidia-related again and reïnstalling the drivers.

Edit 11/I was wrong: did that and same problem as before.

Edit 12/infinity: `Xorg --configure` complains about not finding fbcon, making me slam the desk hard enough to reboot my machine. (fixed by installing `xserver-xorg-video-fbdev`)